# Mysql: многотабличный запрос поиска друзей и их репостов

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Пытаюсь сделать уведомления по нескольким таблицам, сам скрипт в основном работает, выдает те данные которые нужны, но с одним недочетом.

Вывод происходит из таблицы `friends` и `repost`, если в обеих таблицах есть нужная запись то все нормально выводит, но если допустим во `friends` есть а в `repost` нет, то выводится запись `friends` и с ним вся таблица `repost` и так с каждым найденным `id`.

---

Вот сам запрос и вывод в цикле:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT 
            `friends`.id AS friends_id,
            `repost`.id AS repost_id
          FROM
            `friends`,`repost` 
          WHERE 
            (`friends`.id_2 = '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `friends`.id_1 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `friends`.obrabotan = '1') 
            OR
            (`repost`.users = '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `repost`.users2 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `repost`.status = '1')";
$sql_yvedom = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_yvedom)){
    echo $row["friends_id"].$row["repost_id"];
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь, не знаю как построить условие, чтобы если `repost` нет, то не выводило всю таблицу.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/, почти  оно же на русском http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Нашел другой выход из ситуации. UNION.

Вот исходный код запроса:

```
SELECT  T.cnt 
FROM
(
SELECT id_1 AS cnt, date FROM friends WHERE id_2 = '$_SESSION[id]' AND id_1 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND obrabotan = '1' 
UNION
SELECT users2 AS cnt, date FROM repost WHERE users = '$_SESSION[id]' AND users2 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND status = '1'
UNION
SELECT my_id AS cnt, date FROM comment WHERE my_id <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND you_id = '$_SESSION[id]' AND status = '1'
) AS T ORDER BY date DESC
```

Не знаю как этот вариант по скорости работы, и вообще есть ли разница в нагрузке. Но думаю что, если запрос один а не 3, то mysql меньше нагружен. Надеюсь я не ошибся в коде, если есть какие то замечания, был бы рад услышать их в комментах.

Answer (score 1):

У вас декартовое произведение таблиц (`friends, repost`), поэтому если не срабатывает ограничивающее условие, то каждой записи одной таблицы сопоставляется каждая запись другой таблицы. Нужно подобрать ON-условие связи записей из двух таблиц

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT 
            `friends`.id AS friends_id,
            `repost`.id AS repost_id
          FROM
            `friends`,`repost`
          ON
            friends`.id_2 = repost`.users AND
            friends`.id_2 = $_SESSION[id]
          WHERE 
            (`friends`.id_1 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `friends`.obrabotan = '1') 
            OR
            (`repost`.users2 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND
             `repost`.status = '1')";
$sql_yvedom = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_yvedom)){
    echo $row["friends_id"].$row["repost_id"];
}
```

Comment: По идее условие правильное, но что-то не работает. Менял в ON условие по разному, но нет вывода.

Comment: По хорошему дамп вашей базы данных нужен (пусть урезанный), иначе сложно воспроизвести ситуацию.

Comment: Таблица friends ( id,id_1 - подписывающийся пользователь, id_2 - на кого подписываются, date , obrabotan - статус подписки ). Таблица repost ( id,users - кому отправлен пост, users2 - кто отправитель, status - статус отправки ).

Comment: Вопрос актуален, Вы не сможете разобраться и построить правильный алгоритм вывода? Или придется тогда многозапросный вывод сделать( И да, было бы приятным сюрпризом, чтобы вывод происходил по дате учитывая обе таблицы, я понимаю что это через цикл, но если Вам не сложно показать, как это правильно делается?)

Comment: Почти разобрался и нашел выход через UNION, но вот не пойму как добавить ORDER BY date DESC. Каркас вывода такой: SELECT  T.cnt 
FROM
(
SELECT id_1 AS cnt FROM friends WHERE id_2 = '$_SESSION[id]' AND id_1 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND obrabotan = '1' 
UNION
SELECT users2 AS cnt FROM repost WHERE users = '$_SESSION[id]' AND users2 <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND status = '1'
UNION
SELECT my_id AS cnt FROM comment WHERE my_id <> '$_SESSION[id]' AND you_id = '$_SESSION[id]' AND status = '1'
) AS T